# Postgres generate_series return the series timestamp, even when no data

Tags: postgresql

I have a database that has metrics inserted every 3 minutes.  I'm trying to generate a time series to report aggregate values in 10 minute intervals, to use for displaying on a graph.  The idea here is to return an hours worth of data, with the aggregate values combined into the 10 minute intervals.

I have some code that handles this well already:

```
SELECT
    width_bucket(
        created::timestamp,
        array( select generate_series( timestamp '2022-11-19 19:00:00+00', '2022-11-19 20:00:00+00', '10 minutes') )
        ) as partition,
            worker, AVG(hashrate) AS hashrate, AVG(sharespersecond) AS sharespersecond, count(*)
            FROM minerstats
            WHERE created >= '2022-11-19 19:00:00+00' AND created <= '2022-11-19 20:00:00+00'
            GROUP BY 1, 2, worker
            ORDER BY 1, 2, worker
```

This works and it returns the `partition` in numeric form so `2022-11-19 19:10:00+00` through `2022-11-19 19:20:00+00` would be 2 .. but would be ideal if i could get it to return `2022-11-19 19:10:00+00` or `2022-11-19 19:20:00+00` even if there is no data for that series.

Can anybody point me in the right direction or help with how I could do this to return the series when there's no data, along with the timestamp of the series?

db fiddle:
https://dbfiddle.uk/5RZxReoE

Comment: Wouldn't you want to `LEFT JOIN` the output of the series to `minerstats`? In other words don't use `width_bucket()`.

Comment: To be completely honestly I don't even know, i'm new to building my own custom queries, this is what i came up with after hours of reading through other SO questions, I wouldn't even know where to start :(

Comment: The dbfiddle is using Postgres 12, is that what you are working with in the production database?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver yes right now, i hope to update to 14 soon for `date_bin` but right now that's going to take a bit of effort to do the upgrade .. is that what you were thinking of using?  I could try and push for an update if that's the only viable option

Comment: That was where I was going then you could do something like the last query here https://dbfiddle.uk/j-hlhAvt. I am still working out how to do this with Postgres 12?

Comment: See my answer for possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Postgres 13-(no `date_bin`):

```
SELECT
    ten_min,
    worker,
    AVG(hashrate) AS hashrate,
    AVG(sharespersecond) AS sharespersecond,
    count(*)
FROM (
    SELECT
        generate_series(timestamptz '2022-11-19 19:00:00+00', '2022-11-19 19:50:00+00', '10 minutes') AS ten_min) AS t
    LEFT JOIN minerstats AS ms ON created <@ tstzrange(t.ten_min, ten_min + '0:10'::time)
GROUP BY
    ten_min,
    worker
ORDER BY
    ten_min,
    worker;

  ten_min         |   worker   |     hashrate      |   sharespersecond    | count 
-------------------------+------------+-------------------+----------------------+-------
 11/19/2022 11:00:00 PST | NULL       |              NULL |                 NULL |     1
 11/19/2022 11:10:00 PST | testbench  |     776206061.875 | 0.030125000000000002 |     8
 11/19/2022 11:10:00 PST | testbench2 |       842887331.5 |               0.0325 |     2
 11/19/2022 11:20:00 PST | testbench  | 718040215.3333334 |  0.02788888888888889 |     9
 11/19/2022 11:20:00 PST | testbench2 |         687194767 |                0.027 |     1
 11/19/2022 11:30:00 PST | testbench  |      932726496.75 | 0.036125000000000004 |     8
 11/19/2022 11:30:00 PST | testbench2 |         719753390 |                0.028 |     2
 11/19/2022 11:40:00 PST | testbench  | 612414545.6666666 | 0.023777777777777773 |     9
 11/19/2022 11:40:00 PST | testbench2 |         700852403 |                0.027 |     1
 11/19/2022 11:50:00 PST | testbench  |     483093391.375 | 0.018875000000000003 |     8
 11/19/2022 11:50:00 PST | testbench2 |       505780476.5 |               0.0195 |     2
```

UPDATE corrected

`ON t.ten_min <@ tstzrange(created, created + '0:10'::time)`

to

`ON created <@ tstzrange(t.ten_min, ten_min + '0:10'::time)`

Using [date_bin](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-BIN) from Postgres 14+:

```
 SELECT
    ten_min,
    worker,
    AVG(hashrate) AS hashrate,
    AVG(sharespersecond) AS sharespersecond,
    count(*)
FROM (
    SELECT
        generate_series(timestamptz '2022-11-19 19:00:00+00', '2022-11-19 19:50:00+00', '10 minutes') AS ten_min) AS t
    LEFT JOIN minerstats AS ms ON t.ten_min = date_bin ('10 minutes', created, '2001-01-01')
GROUP BY
    ten_min, worker
ORDER BY
  ten_min, worker;
         ten_min         |   worker   |     hashrate      |   sharespersecond    | count 
-------------------------+------------+-------------------+----------------------+-------
 11/19/2022 11:00:00 PST | NULL       |              NULL |                 NULL |     1
 11/19/2022 11:10:00 PST | testbench  |     776206061.875 |             0.030125 |     8
 11/19/2022 11:10:00 PST | testbench2 |       842887331.5 |               0.0325 |     2
 11/19/2022 11:20:00 PST | testbench  | 718040215.3333334 |  0.02788888888888889 |     9
 11/19/2022 11:20:00 PST | testbench2 |         687194767 |                0.027 |     1
 11/19/2022 11:30:00 PST | testbench  |      932726496.75 | 0.036125000000000004 |     8
 11/19/2022 11:30:00 PST | testbench2 |         719753390 |                0.028 |     2
 11/19/2022 11:40:00 PST | testbench  | 612414545.6666666 | 0.023777777777777773 |     9
 11/19/2022 11:40:00 PST | testbench2 |         700852403 |                0.027 |     1
 11/19/2022 11:50:00 PST | testbench  |     483093391.375 | 0.018875000000000003 |     8
 11/19/2022 11:50:00 PST | testbench2 |       505780476.5 |               0.0195 |     2
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use the derived table for generated_series instead of `from generate_series(...) as t(ten_min) left join ...`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, no reason just habit.

Comment: Using this also cuts down my query time from 11ms to 2-3ms! Thanks again!